# What is the standard way to deploy memcached?

Tags: mysql, iis, memcached, cache

I have two IIS servers and two MySQL servers. On all servers I have some available memory (More than a GB). What is the standard way to deploy memcached?

Should I add a new server especially for memcached, or should I use my existing servers? If so, which servers?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Whatever works. It's generally better to separate concerns, but it's also much more expensive to dedicate hardware. We run memcached on a bunch of machines that are used for other purposes, allocating 2 GB out of 8 GB available, and it all runs just fine.